# Lynx, A-Jax alt?

Tags: ajax, noscript, lynx

Humm, I know that Lynx is a text-only browser so scripts, css, images, frames, etc do not run, So I was wondering if there would be an alternate to A-Jax for lynx? I do not like the chances but there may be a tag or some lynx trick to have this use, maybe another attr?

I really don't like my chances of this but it would be quite cool having A-Jax in a text-only browser. :)

Thanks in advanced, Thanks anyway.

Comment: Text based browsers download HTML, and parse it as text. Just fyi.. There's no "ajax alternatives" unless you contribute to lynx and add javascript support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Links](http://freshmeat.net/projects/links/) is a text based browser with some javascript support that may or may not fit your needs.

Comment: lynx is links improved and there is no JS support are you saying that lynx, links improved dropped javascript?

Comment: You've got them reversed.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser)  I'm not even sure about the improved part.  I can't find any evidence that links is a fork.

Comment: humm, I assumed that links with no color that lynx would be improved as similar to vim is vi improved :)

Answer (score 0):

Any sort of server-pulling in Lynx would have to be done on the server itself, so no asynchronous transfer after loading a page.

Maybe support for HTML 5's [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/)?

Comment: lynx don't have features like javascript, let alone websocket.

Comment: websockets are javascript, no javascript no websockets, If it was a html tag attr then that would be pritty cool :)

Comment: lol, not really, I just wish there was an ability for <div livesocket="ws://irc.freenode.net/" name="irc"></div> and a form action set to the divs name.